# Java Event queue get delayed and holds monitor for few seconds

Tags: java, swing, java-web-start, awt-eventqueue

In Swing application, some UI operation events gets lags in execution
and UI and gets freeze for few seconds. when tried to check using

```
ThreadInfo  MonitorInfo[] monitors = threadInfo.getLockedMonitors();
```

and

```
StackTraceElement[] stackElements = threadInfo.getStackTrace();
```

displays and the lines continuous.. to the component.

This happens only in webstart

ex:

```
**HOLDS MONITORS:** [java.util.zip.ZStreamRef@a4f0208, 
com.sun.deploy.cache.CacheEntry@2788c4ea, 
com.sun.deploy.cache.CachedJarFile@294f3e6b, 
com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader@5ce11cce, 
javax.swing.plaf.basic.DefaultMenuLayout@d096bf8, 
java.awt.Component$AWTTreeLock@285a2772]
STACK TRACE:
java.util.zip.Inflater.inflateBytes(Native Method)
java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(Unknown Source)
java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
java.util.jar.JarVerifier$VerifierStream.read(Unknown Source)
com.sun.deploy.security.JarVerifier.readAndMaybeSaveStreamTo(Unknown
Source)
com.sun.deploy.security.JarVerifier.authenticateJarEntry(Unknown Source)
com.sun.deploy.security.EnhancedJarVerifier.validate(Unknown Source)
com.sun.deploy.cache.CacheEntry$3.run(Unknown Source)
com.sun.deploy.cache.CacheEntry$3.run(Unknown Source)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
com.sun.deploy.cache.CacheEntry.getJarSigningData(Unknown Source)
com.sun.deploy.cache.CachedJarFile.getSigningData(Unknown Source)
com.sun.deploy.cache.CachedJarFile$JarFileEntry.getCodeSigners(Unknown
Source)
com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getCodeSigners(
Unknown Source)
java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Don't use quote formatting for non-quoted material!

Comment: Use a `SwingWorker` to offload long running/blocking operations to other thread contexts (other than the Event Dispatching Thread)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the calls to those methods in separate threads? Because you use Swing, it's mostly thread safe. Is it the entire monitor that freezes, or just the window?

Threads are simple, if you've been avoiding them:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() -> intensiveMethod());
thread.start();
```

`intensiveMethod` being the method you call that freezes your monitors. If it's not you calling it, try installing the latest JRE and JDK.

Comment: It freezes onIy the application not Windows ( used separate thread, Thread t = new Thread()..  Its only freezes for few seconds ( 5 sec ) to the 45 till the previous thread completes its process resumes.

Comment: @MadProgrammer suggested using a `SwingWorker`, have you tried that?

Comment: Thread id: 70, name:  AWT-EventQueue-2, state: RUNNABLE [ 
    java.awt.Component$AWTTreeLock@22e7c0ed ]  ACK TRACE:  
    java.awt.GridBagLayout.preInitMaximumArraySizes(Unknown  Source)
    java.awt.GridBagLayout.GetLayoutInfo(Unknown Source)
    java.awt.GridBagLayout.getLayoutInfo(Unknown Source)
    java.awt.GridBagLayout.ArrangeGrid(Unknown Source)
    java.awt.GridBagLayout.arrangeGrid(Unknown Source)
    java.awt.GridBagLayout.layoutContainer(Unknown Source)
    java.awt.Container.layout(Unknown Source)
    java.awt.Container.doLayout(Un)

Comment: Can you post your code to some sort of past.ee like website so I can se what you're doing?

Comment: Guys:  I am using Substance for L&F and all UI operation are not allowed to do in SwingWorker. Sorry i missed to add in query.

Comment: @rathinamsm Ah, I don't know how those work, but if they don't work in other Threads, or even SwingWorkers, I don't know what you could do. `C#` has Coroutines, but Java doesn't.

Comment: Guys:  I am using Substance for L&F and all UI operation are not allowed to do in SwingWorker. Sorry i missed to add in query.         Hope even in non-substance All compoenent creation should be in Ui thread.

Comment: From web start applicaiton:  it accessing a jar when  and the below is found when chcecking monitor hold in ThreadInfo         STACK TRACE:
    java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(Unknown Source)
    java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)    java.util.jar.JarVerifier$VerifierStream.read(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.deploy.security.JarVerifier.readAndMaybeSaveStreamTo(Unknown Source)